# Do you see why my code is not entering in my else condition?

Tags: php

I have a form to insert a image, title, content and a gallery of images to a news.

For my main image of my news and for my gallery images, I want to do a validation about selected image type. I Just want to allow images jpg, gif and png.
If user post an image of another type, I want to show an error message saying 'Only JPG, PNG or GIF images are accepted.'

But Im havin a problem, my validation it seems that is working, but when I fill every fields correctly Im not entering in my else condition to do my insert.

Im not entering here:

```
else{
echo  'test'; // this test never appear
//here I have an insert but its not entering here
}
```

Do you see where might be the problem?

So I have my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="label">
        <span class="field">Title</span>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" />
    </div>         
     <div>
        <span>Main image:</span>
        <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" /> 
     </div>


     <div class="galerry">               
     <div>
         <span class="field">Gallery:</span>
         <input type="file" name="gb[]"  multiple="multiple" accept="image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"  />       
        </div>  
    </div><!--/gallery-->
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="sendForm"/>
</form>
```

And then I have my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){

    $f['title'] = $_POST['title'];
    $f['content'] =$_POST['content'];
    $img = $_FILES['img'];
    $extPerm = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
    $gb = $_FILES['gb'];
    print_r($img);

    if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])){
        echo 'Please fill all fields';
    }
    else if(!in_array($img['type'],$extPerm)){
        echo 'Only JPG, PNG or GIF images are accepted.';
    }
    else if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name'][0]){
        print_r($_FILES['gb']);
        $count= count($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        if(!in_array($gb['type'][$i],$extPerm)){
                echo 'Only JPG, PNG or GIF images are accepted.';
        }
        }
     } else {
        echo  'test'; // this test never appear
        //here I have an insert but its not entering here
    } 
}
```

Comment: My guess it that your elseif statement checking for a healthy image is checking that all the file types are ok, and they are, then it's stopping at the end of that clause. Using elseif means only **one** section of your code is going to run, and if it gets into that image section, it will never make it to your last else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer scrowler. And yes I just dont enter in my else when I have "healthy images". Now I understand the problem. But do you see any solution for this? Because with my little experience, Im not see what can I do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for that kind of thing I would use a flag variable, say `$fine`, like this :

```
$fine = true;
if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])){
    echo 'Please fill all fields';
    $fine = false;
}

if(!in_array($img['type'],$extPerm)){
    echo 'Only JPG, PNG or GIF images are accepted.';
    $fine = false;
}

if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name'][0]){
     print_r($_FILES['gb']);
     $count= count($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']);
     for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        if(!in_array($gb['type'][$i],$extPerm)){
            echo 'Only JPG, PNG or GIF images are accepted.';
            $fine = false;
        }
      }
 }

if($fine){//if there was no problem
   echo  'test'; // this test now should appear
   //here I have an insert but its not entering here
}
```

Notice there are no `else` statements, so every possible case is tested. This means you may have multiple errors echoed.

you could also commit your errors to an `$errors` array, then test `if(count($errors) == 0)` for example

Comment: Thank you very much Boris. I was here tailed without finding a solution. And your solution seems very good and worked perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: Boris, Im having one situation with my two first if´s. If I dont fill any field and click on my submit button, Im getting my two first errors. And I just one at a time. It is not correct in this cases use else if? In this example, else if in my second condition.

Comment: yes it is correct. I removed all the elses without really going into what they do. the important part is that your "finally" code doesn't belong in an else :)